# How to declare the TypeScript types of a React Context initial state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've been struggling to declare the TypeScript types of an initial state of a React Context with our errors. It'll store a list of items, and the initial state should be an empty array.

I've tried many options like using an interface instead of a type, using an object to declare the types of `items` and `setItems`, declaring the type exactly as it's inferred, even trying to bypass de type declaration altogether, and I've finally managed to make it work like this:

```
type Props = [any, any];

export const ListContext = createContext<Partial<Props>>([]);

export const ListProvider = (props: any) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  return (
    <ListContext.Provider value={[items, setItems]}>
      {props.children}
    </ListContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I'm not sure if it's the correct way (using `any` doesn't look like it), and I don't fully understand why it works either.

How can I improve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the way I approach it:

```
type Item = {
    example_prop: number;
};

interface ContextProps {
    items: Item[];
    setItems: Function;
}

export const ListContext = createContext<ContextProps>({
    items: [],
    setItems: () => null
});

interface Props {
    some_prop: string;
}

export const ListProvider: React.ComponentType<Props> = props => {
    const { some_prop } = props; // This is here just to illustrate
    const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([]);

    return (
        <ListContext.Provider value={{ items, setItems }}>
            {props.children}
        </ListContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

As you can see I'm passing an object through the Context. The initial state of this object is set to an empty array and a function which returns null; these two values will be overriden and won't actually pass but are required.

The Props from the component I included `some_prop`, just to serve as an example. Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the great example and explanation, it works great!

Comment: I want to specify exact parameters for my function. This solution worked really well for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333188/react-typescript-avoid-context-default-value/61336826#61336826