# React context and nullable values in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm trying to make a context in react that will hold some values as defined by an interface (`Client` in the example below). My problem is that it requires me to make that field nullable in the state interface (`ClientState`), meaning I would have to check for null values everywhere I consume the context. I want to avoid that.

Example code:

```js
interface Client {
  value1: string,
  value2: number
}

interface ClientState {
    client?: Client
}

const initialState: ClientState = {
    client: undefined
}

const ClientContext = React.createContext<ClientState>(initialState);

export const useClient = (): ClientState => useContext(ClientContext);

export const EmployeeContextProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({});

    // abstracted, not relevant to this problem
    const loadFiles = () => {
        setState(
            {
                value1: "test",
                value2: 1
            }
        )
    }

    useEffect(() => loadFiles(), []);

    return (
        <ClientContext.Provider value={state}>
                {children}
        </ClientContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

So far I've tried and deemed unsatisfactory:

1. Giving the `client` field in `initialState` a dummy object. The problem with this is that the real version of this has a large number of these fields, meaning lots of dummy code.
2. Adding a check to `useClient()` for members of the `Client` interface, same problem as 1.

Also of semi-relevance is that I don't need to modify this context beyond initialization and it's perfectly fine for it to be read-only.

Comment: I just want to point out that the only time you will ever actually see the value of `initialState` is when there isn't a matching context available within the DOM. In other words, you will actually never encounter this value as long as there is an appropriate Context provider. The default value that you will get when you call `useContext(ClientContext)` will be the value you passed to `useState` in the `EmployeeContextProvider` The initial value that is provided to `createContext` is basically only for debugging and is never relevant. You may already be aware of this just wanted to make sure.

Comment: I am aware, but this does not solve the problem of the field being nullable, meaning I would have to check every time I use the context.

Comment: The initial value of `state` isn't null, and you never set the value of `state` to null, so it will never be null. Which means, you don't need to check if `state` is null, even though it is nullable. Am I missing something?

Comment: @HenrikErstad does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333188/react-typescript-avoid-context-default-value/61336826#61336826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client` needs to be optional because its value is set from `state` which is initialised to an empty object. The type of `state` is inferred as `ClientState`.

`useState<ClientState>({})` would require all properties of `ClientState` to be optional.

You could force TypeScript to accept an empty (dummy) object *as if it* complied with ClientState using `useState({} as ClientState)` but that means your Provider really will be providing an unusable client until `setState` has been invoked with a real one.

But that seems to be the problem you would prefer, over checking for null/undefined each time you wish to make use of the client...

TypeScript is perhaps saving you from yourself here. If your client really *can* be undefined then you **should** check it every time you use it!

Comment: When force-feeding TypeScript with an object which doesn't match the required type, `as` can still generate an error due to the types not overlapping sufficiently. One small lie often leads to a bigger lie... `useState({} as unknown as ClientState)`

Comment: Because your Provider would not have a suitable value for `state` until the effect has run once, you could conditionally render the Provider and its children. It will render once the client is set.

`return (state && state.client ? (<existing_render_stuff>) : null)`

Comment: Please see my other answer for a more explicit solution without any preachiness ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your very nice answer. I agree that it is not perfect, but the only reason the field needs to be nullable is that the context needs a default value, and the files that populate the fields in the state are read after the context is initialized

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want.

Your ClientState type seemed to serve only to allow the client to be undefined, which you said you did not want, so I have assumed you would rather not have this. Also, it was conflicting with your setState call where you are setting a Client rather than a ClientState.

This allows for a null Client in state, but NOT in the Context. A guard makes sure the Context and its children are not rendered until the client is set.

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface Client {
    value1: string,
    value2: number
}

// Note: ClientContext is initialised with an unusable Client object
const ClientContext = React.createContext<Client>({} as Client);

export const useClient = (): Client => useContext(ClientContext);

export const EmployeeContextProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
    // We allow state to be set to null
    const [state, setState] = useState<Client | null>(null);

    // abstracted, not relevant to this problem
    const loadFiles = () => {
        setState(
            {
                value1: "test",
                value2: 1
            }
        )
    }

    useEffect(() => loadFiles(), []);

    // Guard against null so that state can be provided as a Client
    return (
        state != null ?
            <ClientContext.Provider value={state} >
                {children}
            </ClientContext.Provider>
            : null
    )
}
```