# How to get prop from context

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-typescript

I need to get a property from context for one component. This code works fine on plain JS, but with typescript in BooksCarousel.tsx I got

> Property 'fetchBooks' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)

in context/app.tsx I have

```
import { createContext, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

type AppContextType = {
  fetchBooks: () => void;
};

const AppContext:any = createContext<AppContextType | null>(null);

function Provider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  const fetchBooks = useCallback(async () => {
    
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/books");

    // setBooks(response.data);
  }, []);

  const valueToShare = {
    // books,
    fetchBooks,
  };

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{fetchBooks}}>
        {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { Provider };
export default AppContext;
```

In hooks/useAppContext.ts I have

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import AppContext from "../context/app";

function useAppContext() {
  return useContext(AppContext);
}

export default useAppContext;
```

In my component I have

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import AppContext from "../../../../shared/context/app";

const BooksCarousel = () => {
  //line of exception
  const { fetchBooks } = useContext(AppContext);
  
  useEffect(() => {
     fetchBooks();
  }, [fetchBooks]);



  return (
    <div>
    {*/jsx code/*}
    </div>
  )
};



export default BooksCarousel;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61336826/4462060 answer from Aron worked

```
const TodoContext = React.createContext<TodoContext>({} as TodoContext)
```